# Apply css stylesheet to inline svg element without loading it on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex, svg

here what i want to do is apply inline css stylesheet to the relative svg element on the page by finding its class and applying style inline to the element according to the property defined in stylesheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X6 -->
<svg
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xml:space="preserve"
width="3.237in"
height="3.157in"
version="1.1"
style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 3237 3157"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <style
        type="text/css">
            <![CDATA[
.str0 {stroke:#373435;stroke-width:4.16694;stroke-linejoin:round}
.fil3 {fill:none}
.fil0 {fill:#373435}
.fil1 {fill:#FEFEFE}
.fil2 {fill:#FEFEFE;fill-rule:nonzero}
]]>
       </style>
    </defs>
    <path
    id="_261044752"
    class="fil0"
    d="M267.784 510.417c106.059,-65.5195 214.002,-181.006 171.579,-314.403l-4.24253 -10.8414c-20.7402,-45.723 -69.7632,-62.6919 -116.429,-46.6655 -20.7402,8.95633 -34.8804,21.6839 -50.908,36.7667l-8.95515 8.48507 -8.48507 -8.48507c-16.0264,-15.0827 -30.1678,-27.8103 -51.3793,-36.7667 -46.1942,-16.0264 -95.216,0.942523 -115.956,46.6655l-4.24253 10.8414c-13.6701,42.8954 -11.7851,84.3759 0.942523,122.556 0,0.471261 0,0.471261 0,0.942523 1.41378,3.77127 2.82757,7.54254 4.24253,11.3138 29.2241,74.9471 98.0448,137.639 166.393,179.591l8.95633 5.6575 8.48388 -5.6575z"
    />
    </svg>
```

**so here in the code class 'fil0' should be searched in stylesheet and its property i.e 'fill:#373435;' should be applied to the 'path' as inline style **

 have tried with regular expression a bit but didn't got anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
<script>
  var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
  var fil0 = stylesheet.cssRules[2].cssText;
  var path = document.getElementById("_261044752");
  path.removeAttribute("class");
  path.setAttribute("style", fil0.substring(fil0.indexOf("{") + 1,fil0.lastIndexOf("}")).trim());
</script>
```

If you want to do this with lots of elements you can call document.[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)("fil0") and loop through the results.